# Using Try() mapping it into an Option with Some(errorMsg) in case of error

Tags: scala

I wanted to replace the below code with something using either `Either` or `Try()`. With vanila scala, is there any straightforward way of making the below code more concise? What I seem to want is to have something like an hypothetical`Try(code).toOption.invert`.

```
def calculateSomething(): Option[String] =
    try {
      // execute some side effects
      None      
    } catch {
      case t:Throwable => Some("some error msg")
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: why not have the `try catch` in the caller method?

Comment: In general we have several of these methods and we want to run these little methods and then gather all the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `failed` method of `Try` which is kind of like the `invert` method you're looking for :

```
val option = Try(code).failed.toOption
```

The you can just `map` over it if you only want the error message:

```
option.map(_.getMessage)
```

You can `getMessage` on the throwable or simply have a function that returns a constant (like `_ => "my error message"`) if you want a custom message.